# Processing a payment from Postman to CyberSource failed in authentication

Tags: rest, postman, signature, cybersource

I'm doing integration between postman and CyberSouce. When doing integration between **CyberSource default org** and Postman with POST Authorization(Internet) method   it is working properly. Also when i POST data from Postman to CyberSource default org that time it is also giving response. But when i'm trying to POST data from Postman to CyberSource by using our sandbox Key and shared-Secret that time it is showing "Authentication Failed" message.

Screenshot when i Post data from Postman to CyberSource default org which is working correct.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY9hm.png)

Scrrenshot when i post data from Postman to our CyberSource Sandbox which is throwing an error
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMSUA.png)

Please Note that : When we are trying hitting our sandbox org from this website https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments it is working fine.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Please post an answer if possible with full example.